# Iterate over each element in JSON array and join with rows

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, lateral-join

I am trying to write a SQL query that cross joins each row with its own JSON array elements.
Let's say this is the data we have (I know, it doesn't make much sense):

```
| id | name | info                                            |
|----|------|-------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | john | [{score: 20, point: 10},{score: 25, point: 15}] |
| 2  | jane | [{score: 25, point: 15},{score: 35, point: 45}] |
```

What I am trying to get as an end result looks like this:

```
| id | name | score | point |
|----|------|-------|-------|
| 1  | john | 20    | 10    |
| 1  | john | 25    | 15    |
| 2  | jane | 25    | 15    |
| 2  | jane | 35    | 45    |
```

How can I write a query that does the job? I don't have the grants to create a new function so this has to be purely select statements, not plpgsql stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest with a lateral join and `json[b]_array_elements`:

```
select t.id, t.name, i.obj ->> 'score' as score, i.obj ->> 'point' as point
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.info) i(info)
```

Comment: This is incredible. How can I read more about this technique? The stuff I found for lateral joins is very complicated and I couldn't get any of them to work, this one is so simple. I really want to learn what some of these mean, especially `i(info)` notation

Comment: @ÖzençB.: the [documentatiion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) is a good place to start. See section "7.2.1.5. LATERAL Subqueries".